# Running SVNSync on a windows box

Tags: svn

I am trying to get SVN Sync running on my home server (windows home server) on a scheduled task to copy all changes from my main SVN server by way of a backup.

I have my main SVN server set up and I have an empty repository with 1 user - svnSync set up on my home server.

I have tried running svnsync on my home server but am having no luck so far.

First off it asked me for the Administrator password - is that normal? How do I cope with that in my script.

When I entered all the usernames and passwords I got this message:

```
svnsync: Repository has not been enabled to accept revision propchanges; ask the administrator to create a pre-revprop-change hook
```

I've no idea what to do to fix that!

Can someone help me out with a batch file to do what I want.

One other question. Will the username of the original person who checks code in be retained in the mirror or will everything be checked in as svnSync?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using svnsync on our production subversion servers at work.  The step that you appear to be missing missing is enabling revision property changes on your sink (destination) repository.  Do this by creating an empty pre-revprop-change hook in your sink subversion repository.  (You will find a template in the hooks subfolder of your sink subversion repository).

The admin password thing is a more generic permissions issue.  The process that runs the svnsync will of course need write permissions to the repository.  At work I have a local   user that has write permission to the destination repository and use the --source-username and --source-password options to use a read only username on the source repository.

Yes the author names are faithfully replicated even if they do not exist as users with access on the destination repository.

For more details see the subversion [book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) replication [section](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication)

Comment: To create an empty pre-revprop-change hook: go to the repository directory, then into the hooks directory, and create a new empty file pre-revprop-change.bat. (SVN runs this to check if you're allowed to change revision properties. Having an empty file means the process exits successfully, so changing revision properties is always allowed.)